# How to mount BlindWrite B6T/B6I image on Debian Jessie?

Tags: debian, mount, images

I got a [BlindWrite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlindWrite) `B6T` / `B6I` image (two formats, first is descriptor, the other is data ) that I would like to mount on Debian Jessie as a virtual disk.

I was looking around for how I could accomplish this and found [CDEmu](http://cdemu.sourceforge.net), which has no package on Debian Jessie.

---

**Edit**

I did used CDEmu to solve this, if you know another way, please add another answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did solve this using [CDemu](http://cdemu.sourceforge.net).

1. First I got CDemu from an [Ubuntu PPA](https://launchpad.net/~cdemu/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), because it's easier to install and maintain than having to compile and install from source.
   Just setup the PPA on Debian and run `$ sudo aptitude update` and then `$ sudo aptitude install cdemu-client gcdemu-` to install the client, but don't install the graphical interface, emit the `gcdemu-` to also install the graphical interface of CDEmu.
2. Navigate to the path where both B6T and B6I files are (obligatory or you won't be able to mount the virtual CD filesystem, step 4.2.): `cd my_path/`
3. Load the image on the CDEmu daemon: `cdemu load 0 ./my_image.B6T`
4. Mount the virtual CD filesystem:

   4.1. Check which device has the virtual disk: `cdemu device-mapping`

```
Device mapping:
DEV   SCSI CD-ROM     SCSI generic
0     /dev/sr1        /dev/sg2
```

4.2. Mount the filesystem: `sudo mount /dev/sr1 /media/vcd/`

Done, you can navigate to `/media/vcd/` and browse the virtual disk contents.